# How to extract image from .bin file

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, binary, bin

I have an homework that requires me to read two images as 8 bit gray pixels, (inputFile >> image1) and perform operations on them such as adding them one on top of another. I'm supposed to use operator overloading for this problem. But to create the "Image" class and overload the ">>" operator from them, I need to first be able to read the image in a meaningful way.

I've tried reading from the file and assigning it to an int for each bit, but output is all 0's. When I try to assign what I need to a char, output is all garbage. Then I thought maybe the numbers are floats, and assigned them to float, but they still all were 0's.

```
double k;
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        input >> hex >> k;
        cout << hex << k;
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard "input" operator `>>` is really for *text* files. If you have a raw binary file you need some other way of [reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) the data.

Comment: Scroll down to *"Binary Files"* on this page for example... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/